# How to call a javascript function inside html from node js app.post()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I have to call a javascript function which is present in html file from a nodejs `app.post()`. I have to call `openup()` as soon as the request goes to `app.post(/process-view-dnd-registration)`. The html file here contains the design for the popup that is to be displayed. I tried calling the function using `popup.openup()`. But it didn't work. Please find my code below.

server.js

```
app.post('/process-view-dnd-registration',function(request,reply){
    popup.openup();
    var json_blob = ({
    "header" : {
    "event_const" : "CNST_PREFERENCE_REGISTRATION_EVENT"
    },
    "jsonblob" : {    
    "MobileNo":request.body.hidMobile,
    "SubscriberPrefCategory":request.body.ServiceProvider,
    "PreferenceDate": today,
    "PreferenceStartTime":request.body.datetimepicker3,
    "PreferenceEndTime":request.body.datetimepicker4
    }
    });
    request.body = json_blob;
    route.invoke(request,reply);
    reply.write('<script>setTimeout(function () { window.location.href = "/view-dnd-registration.html"; }, 3000);</script>');
})
```

popup.html:

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      //contains the design for popup
      <script>
         function open_popup(){
         alert("calling open_popup");
         $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
         openpopup(); 
         }
      </script>
      <script>
         $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow"); 
         function openpopup()
         {
         alert("calling open popup function");
         var id = '#dialog';
         //Get the screen height and width
         var maskHeight = $(document).height();
         var maskWidth = $(window).width();
         //Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
         $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});
         //transition effect
         $('#mask').fadeIn(500);
         $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.9);
         //Get the window height and width
         var winH = $(window).height();
         var winW = $(window).width();     
         //Set the popup window to center
         $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
         $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);
         //transition effect
         $(id).fadeIn(2000);
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Please help me how to call the function `openup();` in node js.

Comment: from were you calling the http-request?

Comment: How do you send the information to the endpoint ```process-view-dnd-registration``` from your client side?

Comment: We are sending information through form action. But we are suggested not to use ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this like that. There are two different ways:

- **Using Ajax:** in your HTML page, where you have your form, you could use the Ajax request to call your `/process-view-dnd-registration` route. Then, you will handle the response and call the `open_popup()` function directly in your page.

Something like that:

```
$("#formId").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var formData = {
     'test': $('input[name=test]').val()
     // All your input values
  };

  $.ajax({
     url: '/process-view-dnd-registration',
     type: 'POST',
     dataType: 'json',
     data: formData
  }).done(function(data) {
     // Call your open_popup() function here
  });
});
```

- **Handle response in your template:** you can send in your app.post method a response when you call your popup.html template, and send it parameters, like a boolean variable which could be `openPopup`, and then handle it in your template page to determine whether or not to display the popup. It depends on how you use templates in your project.

Comment: thanks for the response. But forgot to mention that our requirement asks us to not use ajax call . Can you please suggest some other way?

Comment: so the Handle Response in your template suggesting won't work?

Comment: @sasi - You should try the second way